# Turing's 1939 paper on ordinal logic

Tags: reference-request, logic

I am reading Turing's 1939 paper on ordinal logic ("Systems of Logic Based on Ordinals", A. M. Turing, Proc. London Math. Soc. ser. 2, 45 (1939), #1, 161-228, DOI: [10.1112/plms/s2-45.1.161](http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/plms/s2-45.1.161).)  Immediately after talking about successively extending axiomatic systems using transfinite iteration of the reflection principle, he says, on p. 197: "Another ordinal logic of this type has in effect been introduced by Church".  Does anyone know what this is referring to?  Turing gives two references in a footnote, but the first gives no details and the second is mimeographed notes which I don't have.

Comment: For those who want to take a look: Turing writes that the ordinal logic is in outline contained on pages 279-280 of Church's *A Proof of Freedom from Contradiction*, PNAS 1935 21 (5) 275-281, available [here](http://www.pnas.org/content/21/5.toc).

Answer (score 3):

Turing was Church's PhD student when he developed ordinal logic. Church apparently suggested the idea of iterated consistency statements as a way to escape incompleteness. [This Feferman paper](http://math.stanford.edu/~feferman/papers/turingnotices.pdf) talks a bit about it.

> Turing [...] decided to stay the extra year and do a Ph.D. under Church. Proposed as a thesis topic was the idea of ordinal logics that had been broached in Church’s course as a way to "escape" Gödel's incompleteness theorems.

Answer (score 2):

I can only refer you to Solomon Feferman's paper [Turing in the Land of 0(z)](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.5555/213990.213994) where the author chiefly discusses Turing's idea of his third paper which you mentioned. (Wikipedia does not contain that much of information on [ordinal logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_logic).)

Edit: Google books' copy of Feferman's paper can be accessed [here](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=YafIDVd1Z68C&oi=fnd&pg=PA103&dq=Turing%20in%20the%20Land%20of%200%28z%29&ots=M_Q7h8kivg&sig=Y0OF0w1vdgs9K9Foeld2A7Fn3DY#v=onepage&q=Turing%20in%20the%20Land%20of%200%28z%29&f=false).