# How do I best learn Turing's ordinal logic?

Tags: reference-request, logic

"The Essential Turing" is a book that compiles a list of Turing's papers.
It has a section about Turing's ordinal logic which is confusing.
I want a more straightforward resource on this.

Can anyone recommend a good resource on it?

Comment: You can see [here](http://math.stanford.edu/~feferman/papers/turingnotices.pdf) with biblio.

Comment: And see Torkel Franzén, [Inexhaustibility: a non-exhaustive treatment](https://books.google.it/books?id=GefuAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y) (2004).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA What does "Inexhaustibility: a non-exhaustive treatment (2004)" teach specifically?

Comment: "The inexhaustibility of mathematical knowledge is treated based on the concept of transfinite progressions of theories as conceived by Turing and Feferman" and try with Amazon's [preview](http://www.amazon.com/Inexhaustibility-Non-Exhaustive-Treatment-Lecture-Notes/dp/1568811756) of ToC. Unfortuantely, you cannot  browse it on googlebooks.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Can it substitute "Systems of Logic Based on Ordinals (1938)" by Turing?

Comment: See also likns in this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96558/turings-1939-paper-on-ordinal-logic).

Comment: And finally this short [paper](http://math.stanford.edu/~feferman/papers/turing.pdf) by Feferman with biblio (see Franzen book).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Is there a textbook or anything that explains everything about turing's ordinal logic on the paper comprehensively and makes it unneccesary to read other materials? Jumping from reference to reference is difficult for beginners.

Comment: I suppose that there is no textbook on it; for sure it is not a topic for beginners. You can see [here](https://books.google.it/books?id=5G4Eya27gCgC&pg=PA71) Feferman's preface to the reprint of Turing's paper.

Comment: I'd second Mauro's recommendation of Franzen's book.  It takes you from elementary logic and formal number theory all the way through Feferman's developments of Turing's ideas; since Franzen keeps formalities to a minimum, it gives even relative beginners a shot at making some sense of a fairly technical topic.  Of course, whether something counts as "substitute" for something else depends on what you wanted the first thing for.